# visual representation of a 3 level hierarchy in the same view in odoo 14

Tags: odoo-14

In Odoo (14) it's very common that a one to many relationship is represented in a view as a box containing a list of rows, each row representing one record in the linked entity (table)

The common behavior is that these rows can be clicked on and a click on one of the rows opens a form view on the same record

Is it possible to have a view in which such rows, in their turn, can be exploded (in the same view) and show another list of rows (as a sort of third level in the hierarchy ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible with the basic tree view to have collapsible rows that are not aggregates.

You would have to extend the functionnality of the basic tree view component in odoo to do this, or settle for another UI.